# How to load balance users over an ejabberd cluster?

Tags: xmpp, load-balancing, ejabberd, cluster-computing

I need to cater for 20,000 connected users in a 4-node ejabberd cluster. How would you distribute incoming connections over multiple ejabberd nodes?

Comment: this maybe a better question for serverfault.com

Comment: @PaulStack yep possibly, unless there is an ejabberd module that helps achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

To load balance XMPP TCP/IP traffic, you simply need to but a TCP/IP load balancer. From HAProxy, to Amazon LBS or BIGIP, choose your favorite one.

Answer (score 3):

A way to load balancing without introducing SPOFs is to use multiple [SRV records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record).
IF the clients you are providing the service to support it (i.e. they perform DNS queries to _xmpp-client._tcp.yourdomain), then you get load balancing (with "weights" inside the same priority group) and failover too (assigning a lower priority to a failover group).